# probability of $i$ heads

Tags: probability

If I toss a biased coin $n$ times, what is the probability of getting at least $i$ heads?

The probability of getting exactly $i$ heads with an unbiased coin is $\binom{n}{i}2^{-n}$ I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The probability is represented by a binomial distribution.  Let $K$ be the number of heads.  Say the probability of getting a head is $p$.  Then to get at least $i$ heads out of $n$ flips is

$$P(K \ge i) = \sum_{j=i}^n \binom{n}{j} p^j (1-p)^{n-j}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $H$ be the number of heads you get.

$$P(H \geq i) = P(H = i) + P(H = i+1)  + P(H = i+2) + \cdots $$