# Probability of getting high heads total

Tags: probability

**Probability of getting high heads total in long coin-toss sequence**

If I flip a coin 300 times, what is the probability of getting head at least 200 times?

Comment: Innuendo.${{}}$

Comment: Sorry, trying not to burst out laughing right now. Anyways, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you know about binomial distribution and its approximation with a normal distribution?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346005/probability-of-i-heads?rq=1 . But you may use the normal approximation for calculating the probability (see [Central limit theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem)).

Comment: I am new in probability theory, can anyone suggest  me what are the steps of learning probability theory  with proper source or link?

Comment: [Normal Approximation to the binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation)

Comment: @MSHossain Khan Academy is a really good starting point. https://www.khanacademy.org/math/probability 

Math textbooks and workbooks are also very important.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the coin we assume is a fair coin: $p=\frac{1}{2}$

The number of times we flip the coin is: $n=300$

The number of times we are interested in achieving is $k=200$

Thus, the average is $\mu = np = 150$

The standard deviation is $\sigma = \sqrt{np(1-p)} = \sqrt{75} = 5\sqrt{3}\approx 8.66$

So, letting $X$ be binomially distributed $X\sim B(n,p)$ and $Y$ be normally distributed $Y\sim N(\mu,\sigma)$, and $Z$ be the standard normal distribution $Z\sim N(0,1)$ we use the normal approximation to the binomial:

$$Pr(X\geq 200) \approxeq Pr(Y\geq 199.5) = Pr(Z\geq \frac{199.5 - 150}{5\sqrt{3}})\approx Pr(Z\geq 5.7158)$$

I.e. it is the probability of appearing 5.7158 standard deviations above the mean.

This is a *very* unlikely event.  Most tables don't even go that high.  Using a calculator such as [this one](https://www.fourmilab.ch/rpkp/experiments/analysis/zCalc.html) you find the probability is around $5.47\times 10^{-9}$